# How do I solve a double absolute value inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How do I solve this?

> |x-2| > |x-4|

Do I split the inequality up into two as so?

> -(x-2) > x-4
>
> x-2 > -(x-4)

Comment: You should have three sections: $x\lt 2, 2\le x\lt 4, x\ge 4$...

Comment: With a double absolute value inequality you can usualy just square both sides, remove the absolute value symbol, and then solve the resulting equation.

Comment: Instead of mucking around with symbolic algebra, in this case, it is much more intuitive and instructive to simply sketch the two functions of $x$ and see where one is above the other...

Answer (score 5):

You are given:$$|x-2|\gt|x-4|$$Since both sides have an absolute value, we can just square both sides and remove the absolute value symbol (since the square of any number is always non-negative). So we get:$$(x-2)^2\gt(x-4)^2$$$$\therefore x^2-4x+4\gt x^2-8x+16$$$$\therefore -4x+4\gt-8x+16$$$$\therefore 4x\gt12$$$$\therefore x\gt3$$

Comment: Perfectly valid answer, but a side comment: It think that it is not the fact that the square of any number is always non-negative that makes this possible, but the fact that there's a one-to-one and monotonically increasing correspondence between a number's absolute value and its square.  If we took the sine of both sides and added $1$, that too would be non-negative, but it would not yield the correct answer.

Comment: @BrianTung - thanks for the insight. I never thought of this in that manner - you learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Henning Makholm's idea of sketching the two functions.

But aside from that, it is also useful to build the intuition that in one dimension, $|x-a|$, for any $a$, is simply the (positive) distance that $x$ is from $a$ on the number line.  So, if $|x-2| > |x-4|$, that simply means that $x$ is further from $2$ than it is from $4$.  For what values of $x$ is that the case?

Answer (score 3):

For the rigorous non-squaring approach, we have

$$\begin{align}x\lt 2&: -x+2\gt -x+4\\
2\le x\lt 4&: x-2\gt -x+4\\
4\le x&: x-2\gt x-4\end{align}$$

We immediately see that the first and third cases are resolved: there are no solutions for $x\lt 2$, and all $x\ge 4$ are solutions.  So the second case remains, and we get $2x\gt 6\to x\gt 3$.  Putting all of this together, we arrive at the simple solution of $x\gt 3$.

Answer (score 1):

With an inequality where there are 2 absolute value equations on either side of the inequality i.e. $|ax+c| > |bx +d|$.

All you have to do is make both positive, and then a separate inequality where 1 absolute value is negative.

Both Positive:
$$|x-2| > |x-4|$$
$$x-2 > x-4$$
$$0>-2$$
The $x$'s cancel out, so this equation is no use to us.

One is negative:

$$|x-2| > |x-4|$$
$$x-2 > -(x-4)$$
$$x-2 > 4-x$$
$$2x > 6$$
$$\therefore x>3$$

So you do end up "splitting" it into 2 inequalities, but you only make 1 of them negative.

Comment: There are three cases.  Please read the answer posted by abiessu.